# Seperate comma and get value from another table and concatenate result value

Tags: mysql

Suppose firstly my table1 is:

```
id name
----------
1  abc
2  bcd
3  cde
```

In table2 i store

```
id table1_id
------------
1  1,2
2  1,3
3  1,2,3
```

I want output like this

```
id table1_value
----------------
1  abc,bcd
2  abc,cde
3  abc,bcd,cde
```

Please help me in with mysql query..

Comment: You can now see the benefits of Normalization and cons of storing CSV values in RDBMS. You can find hacky solutions(will be utterly slow with a decent data size) for this problem, but the real problem is your table structure.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/20860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a query which should meet your requirements.  As @GurV commented above, you should avoid storing CSV data in your table, which is not normalized, and which thwarts much of the power which MySQL has as a relational database.

```
SELECT t2.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name ORDER BY t1.name) AS table1_value
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.table1_id) > 0
GROUP BY t2.id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester